# Converting nested list for use in Mathematica

Tags: python, arrays, list, wolfram-mathematica

So I have a nested list of 3 x 3 matrices like

```
a = [ [[1,0,3],[0,1,2],[-1,4,-8]], ... ]
```

And I am trying to find an efficient way to convert it to a list that Mathematica can read. In this case I was thinking of converting `a` to a string and replacing  each [ with {, and each ] with }, then saving this string to a file. My guess is that is not the most efficient method.

Are there any suggestions for an efficient algorithm to convert from python nested arrays to mathematica arrays?

Comment: Show an example of the list that Mathematica can read.

Comment: It seems easier to just save the array as is then import it in Mathematica using the Import[] capabilities (e.g., "JSON" format)

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) with either [`"JSON"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/JSON.html) or [`"BSON"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/BSON.html) or [`"PythonExpression"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/PythonExpression.html) to import the data from a file.  Either of these can be directly exported by Python.

Wolfram Language (a.k.a. Mathematica) can import and export [many formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ListingOfAllFormats.html) with the above being some of the [Basic Formats](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/BasicFormats.html) it supports.

Hope this helps.

Comment: By far the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

Make it as `numpy.array` and `flatten` it:

```
import numpy as np

arr = [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]],
 [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]]

np.array(arr).flatten()
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Or if you prefer `list`, add `tolist()`:

```
np.array(arr).flatten().tolist()
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, if you are worried about the efficiency of reading/writing files you should be reading/writing binary data.  Conversely, if you are committed to text files don't worry overmuch about efficiency.

I see nothing materially wrong in your proposal to write the nested arrays to a string and then replace the brackets with the ones that Mathematica likes.

Personally, though, if the nested array is regular, and if we're sticking with text files, I'd suggest writing a file with:

- a header line containing the extents of each dimension of the nested array, for your example this might be `3, 3, ...` (or possibly `..., 3, 3`)
- and then writing the numbers `3` to a line for as many lines as necessary

If the nested array is not regular you might want to devise a more complex header line to tell Mathematica how to ravel the following numbers.  But whatever you do, keep it simple.

You might be able to do better using Mathematica's recent `ExternalEvaluate["Python", ...]` capability and avoid file-writing and reading.  But this is not something I have experience of to pass along.